# Calendar Overlay Modal mode

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-calendar, modal-dialog, overlay

I have looked through quite a few posts and questions on the site here which suggest that I can insert code into a CEWP to open calendar items "Modally" instead of opening in a new page.

The issue that I am running into is that this is not working. I have tried to run it "as is" as well as downloading the script, creating a .js in `SiteAssets` and linking to it. I must be doing something incorrectly--read USER ERROR!

Additionally, since we are still using 2010, I am not sure that the code isn't for 2013. Can someone point me in the right direction or post the appropriate code to make this happen? I should really teach myself, but with so many resources, reinventing the wheel seems dumb. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please, try with this code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // load our function to the delayed load list
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('calendarEventLinkIntercept');

    // hook into the existing SharePoint calendar load function.
    function calendarEventLinkIntercept() {
        if (SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a) {
            var OldCalendarNotify = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a;
            SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a = function() {
                OldCalendarNotify();
                bindEventClickHandler();
            }
        }
        if (SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4b) {
            var OldCalendarNotify = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4b;
            SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4b = function() {
                OldCalendarNotify();
                bindEventClickHandler();

            }
        }
        // future service pack change may go here!
        // if (SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.???)
    }

    function bindEventClickHandler() {
        $('.ms-acal-mdiv a, .ms-acal-ddiv a, .ms-acal-sdiv a').click(function() {
            EditLink2(this, 'WPQ2');
            return false;
        });
        $('a.ms-cal-nav').attr("href", "javascript:bindEventClickHandler(); void(0);");
    }
</script>
```

[Source](https://davidlozzi.com/2013/02/06/calendar-overlays-keeping-events-in-the-same-window/)